# How to convert as separate df's if column contains mixed values

Tags: r

I have df as:

```
    name    address  value   
    a        NY        22  
    b        CA        run  
    c        MI        NA  
    d        FL        close  
    e        PA        45  
    f        MI        'NA'
```

how to get two separate df's from above df

separate digits with

```
    df1_num = df[grep("[[:digit:]]", df$value), ]
```

df1 consists only number's columns and df2 consists only char column as below

```
     df1_num
    name    address  value 
    a        NY        22
    c        MI        NA
    e        PA        45

    df2_char
    name    address  value
    b        CA        run
    d        FL        close
    f        MI        'NA'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to the answer given by @Akrun we could also try using a combination of `is.numeric()` and `is.na()` to tease apart your data frame:

```
df1_num <- df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$value)) | is.na(df$value), ]
df1_num
  name address value
1    a      NY    22
3    c      MI  <NA>
5    e      PA    45

df2_char <- df[is.na(as.numeric(df$value)) & !is.na(df$value), ]
df2_char
  name address value
2    b      CA   run
4    d      FL close
6    f      MI    NA
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(name=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
                 address=c('NY', 'CA', 'MI', 'FL', 'PA', 'MI'),
                 value=c(22, 'run', NA, 'close', 45, 'NA'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

## Demo

Answer (score 2):

We can create a grouping variable with `grep` and then `split` into `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst <- split(df1, grepl("^[0-9]+$", df1$value)|is.na(df1$value))
names(lst) <- c('df2_char', 'df1_num')
lst
#$df2_char
#   name address value
#2    b      CA   run
#4    d      FL close
#6    f      MI    NA

#$df1_num
#  name address value
#1    a      NY    22
#3    c      MI  <NA>
#5    e      PA    45
```

Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/YZT21607)

It is better to keep it as a `list`, but if we need objects in the global environment (not recommended)

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), address = c("NY", 
"CA", "MI", "FL", "PA", "MI"), value = c("22", "run", NA, "close", 
"45", "NA")), .Names = c("name", "address", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```